# Is there an easy way to apply a mass transformation to a Deedle frame?

Tags: f#, deedle

I have a Deedle frame in fsharp with 45 columns where every column contains floats. I'd like to create a new frame by applying a transformation to every entry in the original frame. The transformation is simple function as follows:

```
let minusLogOfOneLess x = -log (1.0-x)
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like we've missed the unary minus operator when adding operators to Deedle frames! Aside from the unary minus, the rest actually works already.

So you can just change `-log(...)` to `-1.0 * log(...)`:

```
let minusLogOfOneLess (x:Frame<_, _>) = -1.0 * (log (1.0 - x))

frame [ "A" => series [1=>0.5; 2=>0.4]]
|> minusLogOfOneLess
```